# vb.net Custom Windows Lockscreen :: Verify Password To Current LoggedIn User

Tags: vb.net, windows

I am trying to create a Custom Lockscreen for Windows which I am working on, I have a few friends in the project which is doing the design, but I am having problems understand how to verify that the password a user has entered is correct to the current logged in username.

I have `Password` as the variable for a Hidden `Textbox` (using designed circle with kind of like random color change on the sides on each press, just like Arch Linux but a little bit different.)

So how may I verify the users Input to the Windows (Hashed) password? Is it even possible?

---

I have seen a lot of other people do it, they have never shared their codes though.

---

I have been searching for an answer for this for over a month or even more, haven't found anything yet, so please help me.

Thanks, Cecilie.

Answer (score 0):

On the following page Microsoft has documented how to use SSPI to validate a users credentials. It includes sample code you should be able to use.

https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/kb/180548

Comment: I got to be honest I didn't really have any understanding of this SSPI thing here, is there an easier way to do it with microsoft visual basic?